# Query to update a table contents in azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to update a column using Query in azure table storage ? The table has already 100 records and now I have added a new column. For the previous 100 records , the newly added column value is "null" as shown in the image. I just want to set a default value for all the 100 records. I need to know how to update the table.

[image]

Comment: Please improve your question by adding details as much as possible, for example, the description of your scenario, the language you're using, the query you're using. The current description is too simple now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to edit columns in Azure storage, you can use the **Update Entity** functionality to do via Web requests, I'd recommend checking the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2), Then you can also use [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to modify single columns if you have enough permissions.

Comment: Is it the normal query that we use in SQL database or the format is different ?